# Parsing nested JSON data

Tags: python, json

This JSON output is from a MongoDB aggregate query. I essentially need to parse the nested data JSON down to the following to the '`total'` and `'_id'` values.

```
{
'ok': 1.0, 
'result': [
            {
                'total': 142250.0, 
                '_id': 'BC'
            }, 
            {
                'total': 210.88999999999996,
                 '_id': 'USD'
            }, 

            {
                'total': 1065600.0, 
                '_id': 'TK'
            }
            ]
}
```

I've tried 5 different techniques to get what I need from it, however I've run into issues using the `json` and `simplejson` modules.

Ideally, the output will be something like this:

```
142250.0, BC
210.88999999999996, USD
1065600.0, TK
```

Comment: Can you post the code from your attempts with the two modules?

Comment: As mentioned in cpburnz's answer: the problem is the single vs. double quote characters. You need double-quotes, and then a simple call to `json.loads` will work (your JSON string loads fine for me after that switch and is easy to parse).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

NOTE: Your JSON response from MongoDB is not actually valid. JSON requires double-quotes (`"`), not single-quotes (`'`).

I'm not sure why your response has single-quotes instead of double-quotes but from the looks of it you can replace them and then just use the built-in `json` module:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json

response = """{
    'ok': 1.0, 
    'result': [
        {
            'total': 142250.0, 
            '_id': 'BC'
        }, 
        {
            'total': 210.88999999999996,
             '_id': 'USD'
        }, 

        {
            'total': 1065600.0, 
            '_id': 'TK'
        }
        ]
}"""

# JSON requires double-quotes, not single-quotes.
response = response.replace("'", '"')
response = json.loads(response)
for doc in response['result']:
    print(doc['_id'], doc['total'])
```

Comment: I think you mean `json` requires double-quotes in the comment line.

Comment: Yes, I wrote that backwards. Fixed.

Comment: I didn't realize you were making edits. I noticed that some things disappeared a couple times after I fixed various typos so I re-edited to put back what disappeared (probably due to conflicting edits?)

Comment: don't use an unconditional replace on a string with a structured data (a literal for Python dictionary in this case). It might work for some time until it *silently* corrupts the data within. Use an appropriate parser instead e.g., [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19730573/4279)

Comment: @J.F. Fair enough, `ast.iteral_eval()` would be safer solution (really getting a proper response from MongoDB would be best). Given the data which only contains currency code strings and numeric values, a search and replace is sufficient. This would incorrectly convert an embedded `\'` into a `\"` (e.g., `that\'s` would become `that\"s`. Being pedantic, if the response contained a `Date` or `ObjectId`, `literal_eval()` would fail. But still that's probably better if they're not needed.

Comment: Getting this response from trying the above:
>>> for doc in response['result']:
    print doc['_id'], doc['total']
    
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Andrew In python 3 print is a function instead of a statement. It's fixed to support both now.

Answer (score 0):

The response you are getting from the mongodb seems to be the compatible to put for the dictionary type object. as

```
{
    'ok': 1.0,  'result': [
        {
            'total': 142250.0, 
            '_id': 'BC'
        }, 
        {
            'total': 210.88999999999996,
             '_id': 'USD'
        }, 
        {
            'total': 1065600.0, 
            '_id': 'TK'
        }
    ]
}
```

Instead of putting it into multiline string and replacing single quotes in double quotes, can't we directly assign it to the dict type object. and perform further operation on it like:

```
json_data = {
    'ok': 1.0,
    'result':
        [
            {
                'total': 142250.0,
                '_id': 'BC'
            },
            {
                'total': 210.88999999999996,
                '_id': 'USD'
            },
            {
                'total': 1065600.0,
                '_id': 'TK'
            }
    ]
}
```

And:

```
for data in json_data['result']:
    print(data['total'], data['_id'])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import json

data = json.loads(mongo_db_json)
result = data['result']
for value_dict in result:
    print '{0}, {1}'.format(value['total'], value['_id'])
```

This should work

Comment: Actually the OP said that he tried 5 different ways, didn't mention any specific method. But fair enough, couldn't have been such a simple thing.

Comment: Yeah, this didn't work for the reason mentioned in the first answer. PyMongo is only giving singular quotes in its output.

Answer (score -1):

Your example text is not valid [JSON text](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf). JSON string must start with a [`"` quotation mark](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0022), not `'`; but it seems a valid Python literal that you can parse with [`ast.literal_eval()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

data = ast.literal_eval(input_string)
for item in data["result"]:
    print("{total}, {_id}".format(**item))
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/RQtqoq)

```
142250.0, BC
210.89, USD
1065600.0, TK
```

A better way might be to fix the querying process to get valid JSON and use `json` module to parse it.

Comment: All of the values are singular quote responses.

Comment: >>> data = ast.literal_eval(str(response))
>>> for item in data["result"]:
    print("{total}, {_id}".format(**item))

Comment: That will have to do for now, though I would like to actually get JSON out of my Mongo instance...

Comment: @EMS: I don't see json data in the question. Therefore I don't use json parser to parse it. I've edited the answer to mention explicitly that the input should be changed to json

Comment: @EMS: if input is JSON then `json` module can be used. End of story. But the input is not JSON. if OP can't/won't fix the input that looks like a Python literal then `ast.literal_eval` is a safer alternative than a blind `.replace` as [I've commented already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729710/parsing-nested-json-using-python/19730573?noredirect=1#comment29314372_19729976).

Comment: @EMS: ok, I've got your point: you think that actual data presented in the question being non-JSON is a non-issue that deserves at most a comment and could be fixed by such sloppy methods as global `.replace` on the data.

Comment: @EMS: I agree, that is why I wrote: "if OP **can't/won't** fix the input that looks like a Python literal then ast.literal_eval is a safer alternative than a blind .replace".

Comment: @EMS: and here we disagree. I consider traversing a dictionary to be a trivial matter but a more robust handling of the input data to be essential.

Answer (score -2):

This should do.

```
import json

def parse_json(your_json):
    to_dict = json.loads(your_json)
    for item in to_dict['results']:
        print item['total']
```