# Json dump for key, pair in Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, openstack

I have below file which is the result of a json dump.

```
"fdd6a102-359c-4527-8469-4ef01a9c0076": "[\n  {\n    \"resource_status\": \"CREATE_COMPLETE\", \n    \"resource_name\": \"i4_instance_internal_port\", \n    \"resource_type\": \"OS::Neutron::Port\", \n    \"physical_resource_id\": \"5db1d412-9a43-45c7-b72d-0dbe4eb16497\", \n    \"updated_time\": \"2017-07-14T09:00:44\"\n  }, \n  {\n    \"resource_status\": \"CREATE_COMPLETE\", \n    \"resource_name\": \"i3_instance\", \n    \"resource_type\": \"OS::Nova::Server\", \n    \"physical_resource_id\": \"50375d90-5b57-412e-afe3-fdddefbd2f41\", \n    \"updated_time\": \"2017-07-14T09:00:44\"\n  }, \n  {\n    \"resource_status\": \"CREATE_COMPLETE\", \n    \"resource_name\": \"i3_v1_instance_volume\", \n    \"resource_type\": \"OS::Cinder::Volume\", \n    \"physical_resource_id\": \"6750dc3d-e682-4a0c-a177-83a7252822fb\", \n    \"updated_time\": \"2017-07-14T09:00:44\"\n  }\n]\n"
```

This file is messed up I think. It is not in the right format. I researched on how to dump in json

```
def pp_another_json(myDict):
    import io
    try:
        to_unicode = unicode
    except NameError:
        to_unicode = str

    # Write JSON file
    with io.open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
        str_ = json.dumps(myDict,
                          indent=4, sort_keys=True,
                          ensure_ascii=False)
        outfile.write(to_unicode(str_))


class getstackList():
    def getStackID(self):
        stacks = get_objects('stacks')
        myDict = {}
        for stack in stacks:
            try:
                myDict[stack.id] = subprocess.check_output(["openstack", "stack", "resource", "list", stack.id, "-f", "json"])
                pp_another_json(myDict)
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
                print("Error")
```

The output of openstack stack resource list  -f json comes in below format

```
[
  {
    "resource_status": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
    "resource_name": "i4_instance_internal_port",
    "resource_type": "OS::Neutron::Port",
    "physical_resource_id": "5db1d412-9a43-45c7-b72d-0dbe4eb16497",
    "updated_time": "2017-07-14T09:00:44"
  },
  {
    "resource_status": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
    "resource_name": "i3_instance",
    "resource_type": "OS::Nova::Server",
    "physical_resource_id": "50375d90-5b57-412e-afe3-fdddefbd2f41",
    "updated_time": "2017-07-14T09:00:44"
  },
]
```

Now my problems

1. The json dump file doesn't really look like json to me. How can I get it to be in proper format
2. The json dump file is a big one. so I have key as the ID and the value is the list inside which there is another dictionary.(I think so) How do I fetch data in such scenario?
3. I need to check for example if 'resource_type' is OS::Cinder::Volume, how will I get it or else if I need to get the value of resource_type, how will I get it?

It will be helpful if someone can explain me my json file. Or if not, please direct me to the links that could help me understand nested dictionaries

Edited : To fetch the value I did below and is giving me

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

```
    with open('data.json') as data_file:
        data_loaded = json.load(data_file)
        for key, value in data_loaded:
            print(data_loaded[key][0]['resource_status'])
```

data.json is below
[image]

Comment: same error     for key, value in data_loaded:
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: It does contain a lot of data. I changed code a bit.             for key, value in data_loaded.iteritems():
                #print(data_loaded[key][0]['resource_status'])
                print("key",key) This gives me the key. But again to fetch the values  print("key",key, value["resource_type"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Try printing data_loaded.keys() and also the type(data_loaded) ? I am guessing there is some problem with how the json is written to the file.

Comment: print(type(value)) is unicode actually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150809/discussion-between-heenashree-khandelwal-and-mohammed-kashif).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON dump can be viewed as a simple dictionary in python. So for your first part you can use the following :

```
import json
#Assuming 'mydict' contains the json dump

with open('out.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(mydict, outfile)
```

Now coming to the second part, suppose for the first element (fdd6a102-359c-4527-8469-4ef01a9c0076") in your example you need to access the 'resource-status' key of the first element in the list, you simply need to use the following:

```
myjson["fdd6a102-359c-4527-8469-4ef01a9c0076"][0]['resource-status']
```

More information can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306653/python-accessing-nested-json-data).

For your final part, you view [this answer on nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729710/parsing-nested-json-using-python).